# Cast generic type to tuple for debugging purposes

Tags: rust

So I have this little piece of code:

```rust
Some(c) => {
    self.len -= 1;
    eprintln!("{:?}", c as (usize, bool));
    Some(c)
},
```

I added the `eprintln` statement because I need to do some debugging. `c` here is a generic type `V`, but I want to case it to something that can be printed so I can do some debugging. In this case, I know that the values are `(usize, bool)`, but when I try to cast it to that, the compiler complains:

```
184 | ...                   println!("{:?}", c as (usize, bool));
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

How do I print out `c`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast a generic type to a concrete one, without using the `Any` trait which is overkill here.

Instead, just require printability: wherever the type variable `V` is declared, change it to `V: Debug`. Then

```rust
eprintln!("{:?}", c);
```

will compile — no cast needed.

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid you were going to say that. I think its quite silly from an language ergonomics and usability perspective that there exist things in any language that don't have some sane default printable representation. So when I want to debug something, I need to add trait bounds to everything? And then when I am done debugging, I risk accidentally leaving behind a stray `Debug` trait bound? There sure is a lot of friction when trying to debug a Rust program. In any case, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: `#[derive(Debug)]` makes the type default printable if all attributes are of type Debug.